# Getting Value from one ComboBox and set the same value in another ComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I am trying to get the value from one Combo Box and set the same value into the other combo Box here the screen shots:-[click to see screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czvuq.png)

In this first screen i am fetching the username into the combo Box

[click to see screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0eEb.png)

In second screen panel i want to set the value of first combo box as same as the value in the combo box of screen 1
how can i do this..?

Answer (score 0):

are you using java code and which technologies you are using ? I think this should be easy , to set the user name from first screen to some session variable/request variable/static variable and get that variable into second panel.

Comment: i am using java, i already tried session but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: how are you storing this into session ?  which framework you are using for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the documentation to find the method of [`getSelectedItem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem()) and [`setSelectedItem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object))

For example:

```
Object value = combobox1.getSelectedIndex();
combobox2.setSelectedIndex(value);
```